# create new project using maven archetype how to specify custom folder name

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I'm now trying to create a maven archetype which uses `spring + mybatis` framework. There is a mybatis xml file: `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/resources/sql/myapp/DemoUser.xml`, and execute below command to create new project using this archetype.

```
 mvn archetype:generate ... -DartifactId=foo.bar -Dpackage=com.foo.bar ...
```

I want to replace `myapp` to `bar`, that is I want to mybatis xml file in `sql/bar` folder, how to implement this?

Answer (score 3):

My way is in `src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml` to add this property

```
<requiredProperty key="appName">
        <defaultValue>${appName}</defaultValue>
</requiredProperty>
```

Then in `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml` to add

```
#set ($artifactId = "${artifactId}")
#set ($index = $artifactId.indexOf('.'))
#set ($index = $index + 1)
#set ($appName = $artifactId.substring($index))
```

and remember to change folder name to

```
src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/resources/sql/__appName__/DemoUser.xml
```

So when you execute `mvn archetype:generate ... -DartifactId=foo.bar ...` now, you could get

```
│   └── resources
│       └── sql
│           └── bar
│               └── DemoUser.xml
```

refer doc: http://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html

Comment: Where in the pom.xml do I have to add the lines? It doesn't seem to fit anywhere.